# How do I get cluster-distance space from kmeans in R?

Tags: r, matrix, k-means

In python I would use [sklearn's kMean](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) to calculate the clusters, then I get the distance of each point within a cluster to the cluster center by using transform().
I would like to do the same in R, but [R's kMeans](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html) in the stats package would only give me the cluster prediction for each point, or only the distance of each *feature* to cluster center.

(for clearance clusterpoints are documents in my case and features are words/terms, so my input matrix is a TfIdf-matrix)

So is there any other kMeans library that i could use, or is there a fine matrix operation that I can apply to resulting prediction/feature-distance/input-matrix to get what I want?

I would be grateful for any help or hints

Comment: I'm not aware of any package/function, but that's probably because this is rather trivial to write yourself. Won't be more than 5-6 lines.

Comment: Ypu should post the output of dput for a representative Tfldf object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed very trivial ... [rdist](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/rdist.html) computes the euclidean distance for 2 matrixes. So I simply could use rdist(tfidfM, km$centers)